# Drupal date formatting

Tags: php, drupal, date, drupal-6

In lieu of using php's date() function directly, I'd like to trigger a date format that I've created at `admin/settings/date-time/formats`.

At first glance I thought I could do this:

```
format_date(strtotime($date), 'customformat');
```

But it looks like [format_date()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/format_date/6) has a few formats hard-coded and doesn't communicate with the date/time formats.  I could use `$type='custom'` but that would be just like php's date() with some timezone logic.  Of course I want to define date formats in one place, and use those formats in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select in the admin interface how short, medium and long formats for `format_date` should look like, but you can't define extra formats like, `mycustomformat`.

What makes `format_date` different than `date`, is that the result is translatable. Very handy for sites that aren't english.